# Posting data to a php website in c# using http post method

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, post, checkbox

I'm trying to send data to a remote PHP website.  I want to send the data in sessions using HTTP POST.  The thing is, my website is built in C#/ASP.NET, and I don't know how to send my data via POST to this remote PHP website.  (Also note: the POST data I'm trying to send also contains a file uploader and a checkbox.)

How can I POST form data from a C#/ASP.NET to a remote website?

my code which i have used--

public void cvPostDataFirstTime()
    {

```
    string LiveUrl = "TestURL";

    string resume = Server.MapPath("Doc1.docx");
    string boundary = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(LiveUrl)
        as HttpWebRequest;
    CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
    request.PreAuthenticate = true;

    request.CookieContainer = cookies;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = string.Format("multipart/form-data; boundary={0}", boundary);
   // request.PreAuthenticate = true;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


    sb.AppendFormat("--{0}", boundary);
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");
    sb.AppendFormat("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"CandidateRegisterFirstName\"");
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");
    sb.AppendFormat("Gary");
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");


    sb.AppendFormat("--{0}", boundary);
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");
    sb.AppendFormat("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"CandidateRegisterLastName\"");
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");
    sb.AppendFormat("five");
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");

    sb.AppendFormat("--{0}", boundary);
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");
    sb.AppendFormat("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"CandidateRegisterEmailAddress\"");
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");
    sb.AppendFormat("steve.102@fivesol.com");
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");

    Session["checked"] = true;

    sb.AppendFormat("--{0}", boundary);
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");
    sb.AppendFormat("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"CandidateRegisterPassword\"");
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");
    sb.AppendFormat("12345678");
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");

    sb.AppendFormat("--{0}", boundary);
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");
    sb.AppendFormat("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"CandidateRegisterPasswordConfirm\"");
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");
    sb.AppendFormat("12345678");
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");

    sb.AppendFormat("--{0}", boundary);
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");
    sb.AppendFormat("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"CandidateRegisterHomeLocation\"");
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");
    sb.AppendFormat("KA27 8AA");
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");


    sb.AppendFormat("--{0}", boundary);
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");
    sb.AppendFormat("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"CandidateRegisterReferer\"");
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");
    sb.AppendFormat("64");
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");



    sb.AppendFormat("--{0}", boundary);
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");
    sb.AppendFormat("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"CandidateRegisterJobAlerts\"; checked=\""+Session["checked"].ToString()+"\"");
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");
    sb.AppendFormat("");
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");

    sb.AppendFormat("--{0}", boundary);
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");
    sb.AppendFormat("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"CandidateRegisterNewsletterOptions\"; checked=\"" + Session["checked"].ToString() + "\"");
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");
    sb.AppendFormat("");
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");

    sb.AppendFormat("--{0}", boundary);
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");
    sb.AppendFormat("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"CandidateRegisterAcceptTerms\"; checked=\"" + Session["checked"].ToString() + "\"");
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");
    sb.AppendFormat("");
    sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");


    sb.AppendFormat("--{0}--", boundary);
    byte[] fulldata = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
    request.ContentLength = fulldata.Length;
    using (Stream sw = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        sw.Write(fulldata, 0, fulldata.Length);
    }
    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());

        //cvPostDataSecondTime();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is confusing, please elaborate. Some code wouldn't hurt either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) for this.